# Convert serialized HTML time field to java.time.LocalTime

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, localtime

I have created a Spring Boot Controller that takes an Event form object.

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/Event")
    public class EventController {

        @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
        private synchronized List<Event> createEvent(Event inEvent) {       
            log.error("create called with event: " + inEvent);
            create(inEvent);
            return listAll();
        }
    }
```

The Event class looks like this (getters/setters omitted)

```
public final class Event {
   private Integer id;
   private Integer periodId;
   private String name;
   @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
   private LocalDate eventDate;
   private LocalTime startTime;
   private LocalTime endTime;
   private Integer maxParticipants;
   private String status;
   private String eventType;  
}
```

I am getting a Spring Type mismatch error on the startTime and endTime fields

```
Field error in object 'event' on field 'endTime': rejected value
[12:00] codes
 [typeMismatch.event.endTime,typeMismatch.endTime,typeMismatch.java.time.LocalTime,typeMismatch]
arguments
[org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
codes [event.endTime,endTime] arguments [] default message [endTime]]
default message [Failed to convert property value of type
'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalTime' for property
'endTime' nested exception is
org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to
convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.time.LocalTime] for
value '12:00' nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
Parse attempt failed for value [12:00]]
```

The serialized form data is posted using a jQuery AJAX method. The serialized data looks like this:

```
eventDate=27%2F01%2F2017&eventType=REN&maxParticipants=10&startTime=09%3A00&endTime=12%3A00
```

How can I get Spring to correctly parse the serialized time fields ?

I am using Java 8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to supply a [`DateTimeFormat`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html) annotation on the `LocalTime` instances that you want to convert during the form submission.  Those annotations must indicate that the incoming data will adhere to the common ISO time format: [`DateTimeFormat.ISO.TIME`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.ISO.html#TIME).

```
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.TIME)
private LocalTime startTime;

@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.TIME)
private LocalTime endTime;
```

Before I applied those annotations, I was able to reproduce the error you saw.  After I applied those annotations, I was able to POST a form submission to your code sample successfully and verify that it created the `LocalTime` instances correctly.

Comment: Saved me a lot of time. Upvoting. Please add relevant reads (books or tutorials). Thanks,.

Comment: @Vito , thanks for upvoting!  The only resources I used for answering this question were the JavaDoc pages that are already linked from within the answer.  In terms of more general reading material, I've always thought the publicly available [Spring documentation](https://spring.io/docs) is quite good.